# DocuSign - disable completion email to recipient with no DocuSign account

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the CreateAndSendEnvelope api.  Trying to disable the completed signing email that is sent to each recipient after the signing is completed.  The DocuSign account has all the Email setting set to not send completion email.  This works for embedded signer.  However for remote signer where they are receiving the signing email, it does not.  For signer with a DocuSign account, they can turn off the notification in their account preference.  **However, we need to disable the completion email going to recipient without a DocuSign account.**  Try all the signing/email setting in the account and the completion email is still going out to recipient with no DocuSign account.

Also tried setting the UserAccountDefaults element to "true" in the Notification of CreateAndSendEnvelope and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Remote signers are entitled to configure their own email notifications, and as such will receive them unless they register for an account and suppress them in their preferences.